# WPF Toolkit, How to apply date format in C# for datepicker control?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, wpftoolkit

WPF Toolkit, How to apply date format in C# for datepicker control?

Comment: Take a look at [http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: Specify more information. What format you need?

Comment: Required  is dd-mon-yyyy to selected date format..

Comment: In wpftoolkit 4: <toolKit:DateTimePicker Format="Custom" FormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" Watermark="Select Date" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the one way to solve of my problem by using the culture

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");

System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtinfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();

dtinfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd-Mon-yyyy";

dtinfo.DateSeparator = "-";
```

And apply this short date pattern to date time picker.. It works

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker in WPF Toolkit allow only Short and Long formats.
You can use as

```
datePicker.SelectedDateFormat = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DatePickerFormat.Long;
datePicker.SelectedDateFormat = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DatePickerFormat.Short;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you change format following this way. All control have DateTime will be change. I think you need create new template  and create new you custom control