# How to change DateFormat of DatePicker in wpf

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I want then when user select the date from datepicker on textbox it will show the date like 01-April-2012

Please tell me how it is done??
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378484/wpf-toolkit-how-to-apply-date-format-in-c-sharp-for-datepicker-control

Comment: I think it is not an exact match. Unless I am wrong, the user really wants to format the textbox value bound to a DatePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to format your textbox. Assuming the text box is already bounded to the DatePicker, it should be something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DatePicker1, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}}" />
```