# Getting date from DatePicker in format yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datepicker

I have a WPF C# application (.NET 4.0) and I have a date picker. I would like to know if I can change the format date (the text property of the date picker) to the `yyyy/MM/dd` format.

I am using the MVVM pattern, so I would like to know the XAML code, if it is possible to do it in this place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can use this code:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding myVideModelProperty}"
                    Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,-2,0,0" Name="myDatePicker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
            <DatePicker.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                                    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy/MM/dd}}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DatePicker.Resources>
        </DatePicker>
```

Using the datePicker resources I can set the format of its textBox. In  this way, It is not needed a converter, neither a general template and any other extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the `Template` for your datepicker and use this value converter. In the template, the line with `DatePickerTextBox` has been modified to use the `yyyy/MM/dd` format (via the converter) you requested. The template I modified came from [here](http://cuppster.com/2011/02/02/xaml-template-for-the-wpf-datepicker-control/).

Example usage:

```
<DatePicker Template="{StaticResource SpecialDatePicker}" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date}" />
```

Value converter code:

```
public class DateFixerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse((string)value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse((string) value);
    }
}
```

Template code:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SpecialDatePicker" TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}">
            <Grid Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush">#A5FFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" Width="19" Height="18" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="23*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" Name="Highlight" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FF1F3B53" Name="Background" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#BF000000" Name="BackgroundGradient" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.7,0" EndPoint="0.7,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.46,1.6" EndPoint="0.3,-1.1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.48,1.25" EndPoint="0.48,-1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF494949" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Path Data="M11.426758,8.4305077L11.749023,8.4305077 11.749023,16.331387 10.674805,16.331387 10.674805,10.299648 9.0742188,11.298672 9.0742188,10.294277C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077z M14.65086,8.4305077L18.566387,8.4305077 18.566387,9.3435936 15.671368,9.3435936 15.671368,11.255703C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504L14.881817,14.929531C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055L14.65086,12.238613z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" Margin="4,3,4,3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="0" Width="3" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" Name="DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Button Foreground="{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}" Name="PART_Button" Width="20" Margin="3,0,3,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" Width="19" Height="18" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="23*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" Name="Highlight" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FF1F3B53" Name="Background" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#BF000000" Name="BackgroundGradient" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.7,0" EndPoint="0.7,1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.46,1.6" EndPoint="0.3,-1.1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.48,1.25" EndPoint="0.48,-1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF494949" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <Path Data="M11.426758,8.4305077L11.749023,8.4305077 11.749023,16.331387 10.674805,16.331387 10.674805,10.299648 9.0742188,11.298672 9.0742188,10.294277C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077z M14.65086,8.4305077L18.566387,8.4305077 18.566387,9.3435936 15.671368,9.3435936 15.671368,11.255703C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504L14.881817,14.929531C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055L14.65086,12.238613z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" Margin="4,3,4,3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="0" Width="3" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" Name="DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <!-- THIS LINE :: Notice the binding for Text -->
                <DatePickerTextBox  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker},Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource DateFixer}}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" xml:space="preserve"></DatePickerTextBox>
                <Grid Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Width="19" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <Popup Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Name="PART_Popup" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378484/wpf-toolkit-how-to-apply-date-format-in-c-sharp-for-datepicker-control) you can change the culture to get the correct date format

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtinfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtinfo.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

Comment: but this is in the axml? I would like to use the MVVM pattern. Thanks.

Comment: This is not put in the xaml, could you please insert som code in your example so i can understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: @Daimroc MVVM doesn't mean “do everything in XAML”.

Comment: @svick: but I think that the presentation it would do it in the axml. If I have a multi language application, I only want to change the format of the date, and this I think that is responsability of the axml.

Comment: There is no ability in the Xaml to specify a format. So your choices are: adjust the culture settings, or rebuild the control to support date formats. MS didn't think of everything, and if we had to wait for that to happen before they released anything, we'd probably be lucky to have .Net 1.0 beta by now. :)